# RoamingSettings in outlook add-in does not seem to be working properly

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am currently using the `RoamingSettings` in Outlook to store two values. This is the snippet I use to store the values,

```
Office.context.roamingSettings.set("email", email);
Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(res){console.log(res);});
Office.context.roamingSettings.set("name", name);
Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(res){console.log(res);});
```

The first time I ran this both the values got saved. Then I used this snippet to delete the two values,

```
Office.context.roamingSettings.remove("email");
Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(res){console.log(res);});
Office.context.roamingSettings.remove("name");
Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(res){console.log(res);});
```

And then tried to add those two values again I see that only the 'name' is getting stored. I found that sometimes it works (both the values are stores) and most of the time only the 'name' value is saved.

Also another thing I noted was that I had saved another key-pair with key 'userEmail' to check the roamingSettings and I am not able to remove it from the storage even after I used `remove('userEmail')` and then `saveAsync()`

Comment: Which client are you trying this from (Eg: Outlook Desktop, Web or Mac) and are you seeing any error message in the console? A possible issue is that you are calling saveAsync multiple times in a row. You should wait for saveAsync to return and call it again from the callback if you need to save again.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the asynchronous nature of saveAsync. Either wait for the save or save after all edits. By not waiting for saveAsync to complete you are overwriting the roaming setting.

```
Office.context.roamingSettings.set("email", email);

Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(res){
    //Wait for save - callback method.
    console.log(res);
    Office.context.roamingSettings.set("name", name); 
    Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
    });
})
```

Or

```
Office.context.roamingSettings.set("email", email);
Office.context.roamingSettings.set("name", name);
Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function(res){console.log(res);})
```

Comment: I have tried both but still have unstable behaviour ... sometimes email gets set and sometimes name and sometimes both of them gets set. My current snippet is, 
`Office.context.roamingSettings.set("Email", email);
        Office.context.roamingSettings.set("Name", name);
        Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(function (ss) {
            callback(ss);
        });`